# Move decimal place to the right using number formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart in Excel and I would like to change my values from:

0.9 
0.8 
0.7 
0.6 
0.5

to:

90 
80 
70 
60 
50

Is there anyway to do this through formatting the number using a format code? Can you multiply a number by 100 in the format code? The percent format would work, but I don't want the % at the end. I tried removing the % from the Format Code, but that did not work.

Comment: What is your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have a short table of constants like:

[image]

and we want to change the **format**.  Select the cells and run this short macro:

```
Sub FakeFormat()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    Dim r As Range
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        v = 100 * r.Value
        mesage = DQ & v & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
    Next r
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

**NOTE**

This is only a format change, the underlying values are still less than **1**

Comment: Will this work for chart axis? Or do I convert the the values before creating the chart then change the values back to normal after creating the chart?

Comment: It worked. First I changed the value from  .90 to 90 using your code. Created the chart. Unchecked "Link to source". Returned my data to the original value of .90. And the graph displays exactly how i want it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a helper column.  For example in a new column put =A1 * 100 and copy it down.  Have the chart use this new helped column instead of the original one to base the values off of.